whats does ては and みた mean in this sentence?
Context: A character is remembering a conversation he had with his father, and he then thinks:

でかいこと言ってはみたものの、

I know that でかいこと言う means "say something big", but I don't know what ては means, or what variation of みた this is. I think this is the みた that you would say to mean "try it and see", but in past tense. But I'm not sure. And I've never really been able to wrap my head around ては since there isn't any consistent logic behind it. Can someone please offer an explanation as to what these two structures mean and what the rules are.


but I don't know what ては means

This て is the usual "て-form" one, which is also where the っ came from. 言う ("say") is inflected to 言って ("saying"). Then は is the ordinary topic marker. The sentence is something about the act of saying something big; then we find out that the speaker (implied 私が) みる'd doing so - which is my awkward segue to:

I think this is the みた that you would say to mean "try it and see", but in past tense.

Yes; you can't literally see the act of saying something, and it doesn't make sense for this to be about examining what was said, so the "try" interpretation is what makes sense. And yes, it's in past tense. The character previously tried to say something big (or, perhaps, make a big deal out of something, in conversation).
ものの is effectively a conjunction meaning "although" or "despite", similar to conjunctive が. I could theorize about the origins of that, but it would be way out of scope and certainly not guaranteed accurate.

So the て allows the verb to be marked as a topic of は and be commented upon, almost as if the action was a noun. But isn't that just the same function as the nominalizing の? What makes 言っては different from 言うのは?

言って here is the act of speaking; 言うの would be the thing that is said. (Although probably either 言っているの or 言ったの is more likely.)

Notice the pattern でかいこと言ってはみたものの. It uses both contrastive は and conjunction ものの. It means although I did said something big...
Suggested reading:

What does とはなる here mean?

ではあるんだろうが meaning.


